AuthJS Credentials not working on Azure Nuxt SWA
I'm using Nuxt for my web app. For specific reasons, I decided to go with AuthJS's Credentials Provider, but when deploying on Azure SWA (tested on both free and standard SKU), I get a
{"code":400,"message":"Login not supported for provider azureStaticWebApps"}

error when trying to access the deployed version. Locally, everything works perfect.
I've tried changing the staticwebapp.config.json, but it didn't seem to work in my attempt to bypass all Azure authentication. I also set up all the env variables as accurate as possible:
AUTH_ORIGIN=<AZURE_URL>
AUTH_SECRET=<SOME_CODE>
AUTH_REDIRECT=<AZURE_URL>/success

Source code of the auth method I used: https://github.com/jahidanowar/nuxt-auth-demo/blob/complete-app/server/api/auth/%5B...%5D.ts
Since I have a custom solution, bypassing Azure auth (such as AAD) might be the best bet, but I'm not sure which way to go with this.
Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.


Since I have a custom solution, bypassing Azure auth (such as AAD) might be the best bet, but I'm not sure which way to go with this.

To integrate Azure AD with a Nuxt.js app and deploy it to Azure Static Web Apps, follow these steps:

I added the ClientID, TenantID, and AzureStaticWebAppURL in the AuthButton.vue and Callback.vue files to implement Azure AD in my app.

AuthButton.vue :
<template>
    <button @click="redirectToAuth">Login with Microsoft</button>
  </template>
  
  <script lang="ts">
  export default {
    methods: {
      redirectToAuth() {
        const clientId = '<clientId>'; 
        const redirectUri = '<AzureStaticWenAppURL>/callback'; 
        const tenantId = '<TenantID>';
        const authUrl = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`;
        const scope = encodeURIComponent('openid profile');
        const authorizationUrl = `${authUrl}?client_id=${clientId}&redirect_uri=${redirectUri}&response_type=code&scope=${scope}`;
        window.location.href = authorizationUrl;
      }
    }
  };
  </script>

callback.vue :
<template>
    <div>
      <p v-if="error">{{ error }}</p>
      <p v-if="message">{{ message }}</p>
      <button v-if="showLogout" @click="logout">Logout</button>
    </div>
  </template>
  
  <script lang="ts">
  import { ref, onMounted } from 'vue';
  export default {
    setup() {
      const error = ref('');
      const message = ref('');
      const showLogout = ref(false);
      onMounted(() => {
        const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
        const code = urlParams.get('code');
        console.log('Authorization Code:', code);
        if (code) {
          message.value = 'Hello World';
          showLogout.value = true;
        } else {
          error.value = 'Authorization code not found in URL.';
        }
      });
  
      const logout = () => { 
        const redirectUri = '<AzureStaticWebAppURL>';
        const tenantId = '<TenantID>';
        const logoutUrl = `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantId}/oauth2/v2.0/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=${redirectUri}`;
        window.location.href = logoutUrl;
      };
      return {
        error,
        message,
        showLogout,
        logout
      };
    }
  };
  </script>

Here is my complete GitHub repository for a Nuxt.js project with Azure Active Directory integration.
I have added the redirect URLs below in the app registration under Single-page application and Web application as shown.


By using the workflow file below, I successfully deployed my Nuxt.js project to Azure Static Web Apps.
Workflow :
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
          lfs: false
      - name: Set up Node.js
        uses: actions/setup-node@v3
        with:
          node-version: '16' 
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm install
      - name: Build Nuxt app
        run: npm run generate
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_BLACK_SEA_Key }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} 
          action: "upload"
          app_location: "/" 
          api_location: "" 
          output_location: "dist" 

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_BLACK_SEA_Key }}
          action: "close"

Azure Satic Web App Output  :
I successfully logged in using "Login with Microsoft" and logged out by clicking the "Logout" button, as shown below.


